# Use Netrw or Nerdtree in Zsh/Bash to select a file BY BROWSING?

Tags: bash, vim, zsh

Often I find myself in the shell, wanting to insert a filename into a lengthy command.

I'd like to hit a shortcut, and use Netrw or Nerdtree to *browse* for a file or directory, and have it pasted in place into the command I’m building.

#### So if I was in a folder, and wanted to compare 2 files:

- I'd type `diff`
- then I'd like to hit my shortcut, and visually browse using Netrw or Nerdtree, and select a file.
- That filename is now added to my diff command... e.g. `diff /tmp/file1.txt`
- I hit the shortcut again, and browse for the second file,
  `/super/ez/another/file/somewhere/else/compare.txt`
- this then adds the second file to my `diff` command, so I now have:

  ```
    diff /tmp/file1.txt /super/ez/another/file/somewhere/else/compare.txt
  ```

Is this possible using *any tool*? I like Netrw in Vim, but am willing to try new things!

Note that I'm not interested in <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion of filenames using globbing. That works sometimes, but not all the time. I like Netrw and would love to figure out how to use it to select a filename by browsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 2022 version of the answer

Vifm v0.8 or later provides a better way of implementing this via
`--choose-files` option which makes this independent of the location of configuration directory.

##### zsh version

```bash
function insert_files() {
    local file
    while read file; do
        LBUFFER+="$(printf %q "$file") "
    done <<< "$(vifm --choose-files - < /dev/tty)"

    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N insert_files
bindkey '^t' insert_files
```

##### bash version

```bash
function _insert_files() {
    local file
    local files
    while read -r file; do
        files="$files$(printf %q "$file") "
    done <<< "$(vifm --choose-files - < /dev/tty)"

    local prefix=${READLINE_LINE::READLINE_POINT}
    local suffix=${READLINE_LINE:READLINE_POINT}
    READLINE_LINE=${prefix}${files}${suffix}
    READLINE_POINT=$(( READLINE_POINT + ${#files} ))
}
bind -x '"\C-T": _insert_files'
```

---

#### Original answer (2014)

You basically already know the answer from [here](https://github.com/vifm/vifm/issues/67#issuecomment-66357856). It's quite easy to put this all together like this:

```
function insert_files() {
    vifm -f < /dev/tty > /dev/tty

    while read l; do
        LBUFFER+="'$l' "
    done < ~/.vifm/vimfiles

    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N insert_files
bindkey '^t' insert_files
```

I'm not a zsh-user, so I stole structure of the code from answer by Lucas.  As for bash, I was looking once for a way to process output of external command inside shortcut, but didn't find one.

[image: Demonstration]

P.S.  My code contains quite primitive escaping, you might want to improve that and maybe change the way spacing is added between arguments.

Comment: This did not work for Mac, could someone help in this regard?

Comment: Added updated version of the answer which works better.

Answer (score 4):

Zsh allows you to bind a shell function to a key and also has a builtin to put text into your command line. So you can do something like this (in zsh):

```
# define a function that does the work
function my_browser_function () {
  local result
  result=$( some command that returns the filename )
  # print -z $result (see comments)
  LBUFFER+=$result
}
# turn the function into a widget
zle -N my_browser_function
# bind it to some key ("CTRL-X I" for example)
bindkey '\Cxi' my_browser_function
```

Now you just have to get a command working that lets you browse the filesystem in the way you want and prints the result on stdout.

EDIT:
Here is a very basic version of the above function that uses vim:

```
function my_browser_function () {
  local file=$(mktemp)
  vim -c "map <C-A> :cal system('echo '.expand('%').'/'.getline('.').'>$file')<bar>q<cr>" .
  LBUFFER+=$(<$file)
  rm $file
}
```

You can navigate in vim/netrw as usual and then use <C-A> (Ctrl-A) to **A**ccept the file/directory name.

Obviously this is only a very basic function. If you want more functionallity you also might write a vim autoload function and call that from the vim command line with -c.

Comment: You don't want to use `print -z` here (stricktly speaking `print -rz --`) which is more to simulate key presses (might call other zle widgets for instance). Use `LBUFFER+=$result` (or `LBUFFER+=${(qqq)result}` to insert it quoted).

Comment: cool! this is definitely half of it... now to figure out a way to get `Netrw` to select a file and output it to stdout.... I can go `vi .` and browse using `Netrw` to the file. But then I have to edit it and hit a keystroke to copy the name to the clipboard. Must... eliminate... these... extra... keystrokes!

Comment: I've found [vifm](https://github.com/vifm/), which seems to do the "browsing" part - super nice... but when I try and run it using a shortcut via zsh or tmux, [I get a screen dump](https://github.com/vifm/vifm/issues/67) of what appears to be escape characters... any ideas on what this would happen?

Comment: Another file manager which might be interesting for this (like vimfm) is [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/). I also added a better shell function that really uses vim above.